# Is there a way to run multiple go tests without regex matching on test names?

Tags: go, testing

Is there a way to run a subset of go tests with the `go test` invocation? I have a scenario where I have a large number of tests (without a pattern to naming), and I'd like to run a subset of them only. There isn't a rule to which ones I want to run, so creating a matching regex won't work (i.e can't match to run all TestXYZFeature tests). I'm currently using the `-run` argument, which only matches to the test name. Is there a way to 'tag' tests or create a text file of tests to run such that the `go test` invocation runs the specified tests?

I don't *think* this is possible, but I'd like to ask anyway just to be sure. Apologies if this is confusing at all! Let me know if I can be clearer about any of this.

Comment: I like to use [build constraints](https://dave.cheney.net/2013/10/12/how-to-use-conditional-compilation-with-the-go-build-tool) for this purpose, though it really depends on how your tests are organized. I've used build tags to, for example, be able to control whether or not integration tests are run since they take longer.

Comment: you could also use ENV var to check in tests from groups if they should be run or based on that create a function which suits your needs and place it above each test to skip it if needed. Idea taken from https://peter.bourgon.org/blog/2021/04/02/dont-use-build-tags-for-integration-tests.html

Comment: Thank you both! I will explore both these options — they both seem to solve the problem at hand.